# Raster Mosaic changes values to 0 for some input rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, mosaic

For a while I was having an issue where the values for the first two inputs in the raster mosaic tool were not being carried over into the final product. This confused me for a couple hours and while I could find other people asking the same or similar questions online, I couldn't find anyone give a concrete answer into what was causing ity and most of the help threads were left unanswered.

I was able to find an answer to my specific issue, so I thought I would post both the problem, and the answer here to provide anyone with similar issues a potential solution.

The steps that I was taking are: Using the Create Raster Dataset tool I create an empty raster, see below.[image]

I then use the Mosaic tool using the five rasters I wish to combine as the input rasters and the empty raster as my target raster, see below.[image]

The resulting raster (while keeping the same shape as the five individual rasters) has lost the information for the first two rasters (sections 1 and 2) and it replaced all of the values with 0! [image]

This pattern continues if you remove the two rasters where the information is lost and only include the upper three rasters. See below.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately what the issue turned out to be was that I had the wrong pixel type! When looking at the layer properties I saw that the pixel depth was 32 bit, and I knew my raster had both positive and negative values so in my create raster dataset tool I used the 32 bit signed option. However, on second inspection the pixel type is specified as a floating point.[image]

I changed the newly created raster to a 32 bit float pixel type and after mosaicking the resulting raster looked as it should, with the small issue of a seam-line between two of the rasters.[image]

I hope this is helpful to people who encounter similar problems so they don't have to feel as dumb as I did when I realized my mistake! I'm still not exactly sure as to what causes the issue. If someone with a deeper understanding would like to weigh in on that I welcome it.